# Can't get fullscreen resolution on Ubuntu hosted on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running Ubunutu 13.04 in VirtualBox. I have it set up to run in fullscreen mode, but its resolution is much less than what my monitor is capable of and is set up to display on the host machine. When I open up Settings -> Displays, the highest possible resolution setting is still less than what I want it to be to get the most out of my monitor.

I've already installed Guest Additions. What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: I already know the answer to this question (see my answer below), but I couldn't find the solution to my specific situation online, so I figured I'd put it here so others can find it =)

Comment: If above answers doesn't work than try this out. https://askubuntu.com/a/1359881/1357742

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to the VirtualBox options while in your VM (the same place you went to to install Guest Additions) and select `View -> Auto-resize Guest Display`. This should automatically set your VM's resolution to the proper screen size.

Comment: I can't believe it was this simple for me. I literally spent hours trying to fix the same issue for my setup. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: Occasionally, I need to reinstall Guest Additions on my virtual machine before this will work. Does that help you?

Comment: I think we can do like this .. https://askubuntu.com/a/1359881/1357742

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I could get this fixed by changing following setting. VM needs to be shut down to change the setting.

Settings (of the VM) > Display > Graphics Controller > and select "VBoxVGA"

Comment: You are the real MVP. This is what worked for me with my win10 host and my kubuntu 20.04 on vbox 6.12

Comment: +1 THIS HELPED ME! I tried everything from modifying other settings to installing guest additions multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

After struggling over and over and over .... uninstalled all virtualbox guest stuff and reinstalled dkms FIRST and then guest additions, and then was able to do View->Auto-resize Guest Display.

What finally worked:

Either substitute to root or use sudo for each apt-get:

```
$ sudo su -
Password: **********

apt-get remove virtualbox-guest-dkms
apt-get remove virtualbox-guest-additions
```

You might be told it has already been done ...

```
shutdown -r now
```

REBOOT ... NOTE: you will most likely need to powerdown from Virtualbox to reboot

```
apt-get update
apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso

shutdown -r now
```

Now in full screen mode:

Virtualbox Menu: VIEW -> AutoResize Guest Display (Host+G)

You may have to rinse-repeat until it works - took me half a dozen times!  The last sequence worked, but no telling ...

Note that sometime during earlier repetitions of the process I upgraded to the most recent version of VirtualBox (which BSOD'd my PC) but I don't think that was a factor in getting the VM to finally recognize my actual screen size.

Comment: I tried this but with no effect. I upgraded to 14.04 and since then the screen is not switching to full screen.

Answer (score 3):

Not enough rep to comment on user1665886 & danijelc's post so I wanted to add the following:

That solution uninstalls dkms, you need to reinstall it and reconfigure it:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

Once I that was complete, VirtualBox automatically displayed desktop at full resolution of my monitors.

Credit to Dr. Windows [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452979/resolution-doesnt-change-when-resizing-virtualbox-window).

Comment: worked like a charm ! )))

Comment: This method did not work on my system in Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Comment: Doesn't work on Focal Fossa 20.04

Answer (score 3):

If you are facing a similar issue, and none of the above worked check this:

Machine settings -> Display -> Screen -> Video memory

Set it to the maximum.

This worked for me, all the others simply didn't work at all.

Comment: +1 The default 32MB memory is not enough to run higher resolutions.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has puzzled me for two weeks and I just finally solved it.
And now features provided by the GuestAdditions such as full-screen, shared-clipboard, Drag'n'Drop all work.

The most important thing, **do not use** THE "GUEST ADDITIONS CD" come along with the Oracle VirtualBox, which you usually find in the menu "Devices" - "Insert Guest Additions CD Image". ***But*** download the latest VBoxAdditions iso file from the [official webpage](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/), mount the image file in your virtual machine and then run the shell file "VBoxLinuxAdditions.run":

```
    sudo sh  VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Type in the password when prompted.
Restart your virtual machine, then everything should work now.

Comment: When do you see the VBoxLinuxAdditions.run? I can only find it on /tmp/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run

Answer (score 2):

The answer may need some updates as time goes to year 2022. For Vbox 6.1, Ubuntu 20 LTS host and guest OS, most time the non-resize-able VM screen issue results from the so-called "Seamless Mode", which provides a miniature screen for ease-of-use by the administrators.

To avoid this issue, one can first change the "Maximum Guest Screen Size window" from "Automatic" to "Hint", then set "Width" and "Height" to the Maximum Screen sizes the host machine allows, e.g. 3840x2160 for 4K display. This change should be done when one is starting the VM.

After that, switch VM to use "scale mode". The switch option is available under "View" menu item of the VM when it is on the way of starting.

This should solve the screen resize issue for nowadays systems. Don't worry about the Guest Addition, it has been embodied into Virtualbox package already. Check "File"->"Preference"->"Extensions" and one can find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing a similar issue, and none of the above worked check this:

Machine settings -> Display -> Screen -> Video memory

set it to the maximun