# Why was the virtualbox package removed from the 14.04 repository?

Tags: apt, virtualbox, release-management

I'm having some problems trying to run my Windows XP virtual machine after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 today. When I tried to start it a message dialog was displayed saying that the kernel drivers aren't installed, in concrete they should be provided by a packaged named `virtualbox-dkms`. I decided to reinstall `virtualbox` so dependencies will get auto resolved, but the execution of command (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox`) resulted in a message similar to: "cannot reinstall package because the package cannot be downloaded" (I'm reproducing the message by memory).

Then I tried using synaptic package manager gui. The package `virtualbox` and its dependencies are there, but without version number or description. Then I switched to main servers, and tried to update, now the package isn't even there anymore.

It may be a problem with my sources.list file but also may be that for some reason I don't know they decide to remove `virtualbox` from repository.

I think I will try to download the packages from the virtual box site for now but in Ubuntu I always installed virtualbox from repository.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04, Virtualbox package version 4.3.10 is available in `multiverse` repository. So enable multiverse repository and install virtualbox  through `apt-get`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

**How  i know that information?**

```
$ apt-cache policy virtualbox
virtualbox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.3.10-dfsg-1
  Version table:
     4.3.10-dfsg-1 0
        500 http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Package
```

Comment: Great, It was exactly that. I have virtualbox running again.

Comment: Kudos for adding the "How I know that information?"-part

Answer (score 10):

It seems the problem is that VirtualBox is not entirely free software anymore. Because of this, it was moved from
[universe (unsupported free software) to multiverse (unsupported non-free software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#Package_classification_and_support).

From [Ubuntu bug #1164654](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1164654):

```
Please move the virtualbox package from universe to multiverse in raring.
SInce virtualbox 4.2 building the BIOS image requires a non-free compiler (Open Watcom).
Upstream provides pre-built BIOS images which is used instead.
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to install it just now with the command: sudo apt-get install virtualbox. It just took about 3 minutes and it is done.

Answer (score 1):

I have just added VirtualBox 4.3.10 from the Ubuntu Software Centre as normal on my laptop, it was missing just after Ubuntu 14.04 LTS was released but is there now. I did also download it from the Oracle site for my desktop (where I use it most) and had to use the info for installing on Ubuntu 13.10 (which worked OK) when Ubuntu 14.04 LTS was released.

I think it may just have been delayed until after the release date. Both installations work OK.