# How to install VirtualBox after prior removal?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I had previously uninstalled VirtualBox. Now, I'm trying to re-install it; but, it is not installing.

Here are my actions and results:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox
    [sudo] password for sudarsan: 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Package virtualbox is not available, but is referred to by another package.
    This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
    is only available from another source
```

However the following packages replace it:
  virtualbox-qt

```
N: Ignoring file 'virtualbox.list.save.3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'virtualbox.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'virtualbox.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Package 'virtualbox' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Have you removed multiverse repository ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/453096/why-was-the-virtualbox-package-removed-from-the-14-04-repository

Answer (score 1):

You have three problems.

1. You should always do a `sudo apt-get update` before your `sudo apt-get install`. Next, you need to use the correct package name for Virtualbox which is **virtualbox**, or **virtualbox-5.1** if you have the updated repository in your **/etc/apt/sources.list**...

```
deb download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial non-free contrib
```

2. You have 3 invalid files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/, and need to delete them with:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list.save.1  
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list.save.2  
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list.save.3
```

3. The file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list` is invalid and needs to be edited.

Cheers, Al

Comment: The package name in the Ubuntu archive is `virtualbox`.

Comment: You're correct if you want virtualbox 5.0, but if you want the latest version 5.1, you may need to add a repository to get it. "**deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial non-free contrib**". Cheers, Al

Comment: I get virtualbox 5.1 from the Ubuntu archive anyway since I'm on 16.10. ;) But it's possible that the OP's problem is related to previous enabling and later disabling of that external repository.

Comment: sudarsan@sudarsan-Inspiron-3551:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Type 'trusty' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: sudarsan@sudarsan-Inspiron-3551:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:

Comment: **Did you delete the files I suggested?** Please edit your question and add the results of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
sudo apt purge virtualbox
sudo apt update
sudo apt install virtualbox
```