# How to stretch ubuntu screen in VM Virtual Box so it will be same as my home system - windows 8?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, resolution, virtualization

I just started Ubuntu 14.01 on my VM VirtualBox virtual machine. VM windows has resolution ~600x500. Ubuntu system started and it is showing in this small screen. When I had tried to open some work windows, I realised, that real Ubuntu resolution is much more than screen of VM Virtual Box.

How I can set system resolution so it will be equal to VM window or how to set VM window so it will be equal to Ubuntu system resoltion?

Answer (score 1):

You must install Virtualbox Additions:

Click on | Devices->Insert Guest Additions CD Image | or press CTRL+D

After you have done this, you can change Ubuntu's resolution by launching system settings from the launcher:

| All settings->Display |

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Firstly, I tried what you said and restarted my pc. Secondly, I did actions, suggested in [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/459475/342574) answer (well, guess, it is same as you suggested, but by console). After that I restarted computer and got same resolution. Also, I tried suggestions from [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/483453/342574) answer and I still get same problem – same resolution. There is still only 640x480 option in Settings -> Display and still vm window doesn't stretch to guest screen size.

Comment: Are you using the newest version of Virtualbox?

Comment: I am not sure. Not newest ver of VitualBox can cause such problem? Reinstalling VB additions right now, but I am not sure it will help me

Comment: Try switching between video modes. |rightCTRL+F| twice

Comment: You can also try pressing alt+ctrl+Enter in the guest window to maximize it

Comment: I don't think auto size works for Ubuntu, or any other OS except for Windows. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First I have the CD/DVD set to Host with no disc in the drive, then set Display memory to at least 4 MB to use 32bit/8*1024*768*(number of monitors)  I used 16 MB to try and get two display screens up and running.

Next Start the machine and once it is up and running, click on Devices and 'Insert Guest Additions CD Image' or hit <kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, where <kbd>Host</kbd> in my case is <kbd>Right Control</kbd>.

Next it will prompt you to do the install into your virtual machine.  After it completes, then restart the virtual machine and it will auto-size to your maximum resolution.

[image]

First I have the CD/DVD set to Host with no disc in the drive, then set Display memory to at least 4 MB to use 32bit/8*1024*768*(number of monitors) I used 16 MB to try and get two display screens up and running.

[image]

Next Start the machine and once it is up and running, click on Devices and 'Insert Guest Additions CD Image' or hit Host+D which in my case is Right Control key plus the D key. Next it will prompt you to do the install into your virtual machine.

[image]

After it completes, then restart the virtual machine and it will auto-size to your maximum resolution.