# Unable to maximise Full-screen with proper quality on VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, display-resolution

I recently installed ubuntu on a Virtual Machine on Windows.
It works perfectly fine, except that I can only use it in the minimized version.
Several attempts to resolve this issue have been made by myself:

Host+F just shows me the exact same screen surrounded by black screen.

On ask ubuntu the following advise was given:
[Can't get fullscreen resolution on Ubuntu hosted on VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310320/cant-get-fullscreen-resolution-on-ubuntu-hosted-on-virtualbox)

I was considering the advise from the community yet there have been the following issues
The option Auto-resize guest display is disabled and I couldn't find out how to fix it.
Also under
[Settings for display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqFlq.png) most of the icons were disabled. The only thing left to adjust was the scale factor. I configured it to be 150% instead of 100%. Now the screen is bigger but blurred.

The following source provided different information on how to solve this problem.

https://ma.ttias.be/auto-resize-screen-size-windows-10-guest-vms-virtualbox/

Nevertheless, when click "Insert guest additions CD image" the following Error Message appears:

[Error Message: Insert guest additions CD image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trcf2.png)

Edit: [Error Message with details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Fxz.png)

If somebody could find out, why I can't use most of the icons in this OS or give me a different advise on the topic respectively the aforementioned error message I would be very grateful.

Comment: For that last error message, can you click the “Details” option? Error messages on Windows are almost criminally opaque, so every little bit of detail helps …

Comment: Sure, already done!

Comment: Silly question, but is the Ubuntu `.iso` file still appearing as “inserted” in VirtualBox? If so, you’ll need to eject/remove it before the guest additions can be used.

Comment: I am new to ubuntu but I assume it is under Files > VBox_GAs_6.1.26 ?

Comment: If not, it would be helpful if you could describe the location where I can find it

Comment: This would be in the Windows part of VirtualBox. In the menu: Devices ⇢ Optical Drives ⇢ Remove Disk from Virtual Drive

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I could auto-resize the display with proper resolution!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the resolution in your vm ubuntu.

From

```
settings -> Displays -> Resolution
```

See [image: this image]